# Java/Selenium code to click a button in a form which is in a frame

Tags: java, selenium

Being new to both Selenium and Java I am trying to figure out how to login into a web app on the local intranet (evaluating Selenium vs SilkTest).

Below you can find the html code of the login form:

```
<head>
<frameset id="myFrameSet" onload="initPage()" framespacing="0" rows="*,0">
<frame id="ContentFrame" frameborder="NO" noresize="NORESIZE" src="/webapp/servlet/frameserver?name=temp\101023065f3049414ff56b2fb27fb9_10102306576e36914ff484fb3e7f90_content261.htm&encoding=UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<body background="../images/ingbgrnd.gif">
<form id="inputForm" target="_parent" onsubmit="return(onSubmit());" method="post" action="pageserver">
<input type="hidden" value="ACTION_NEXT" name="action">
<div align="left">
<center> </center>
<table width="578" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="6" align="left"> </td>
<td width="121" align="left">
<label class="clsform" for="SOME-USER-ID">Name:</label>
</td>
<td width="187" align="left">
<input type="text" value="" tabindex="1" size="15" name="SOME-USER-ID" mandatory="yes">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="187" align="left">
<input type="password" value="" tabindex="2" size="15" name="SOME-USER-PSWD-TXT" mandatory="yes">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td width="6" align="left"> </td>
<td width="316" align="left" colspan="2">
<p align="center">
<input width="143" type="image" border="0" height="38" tabindex="4" src="../english/images/submit.gif" alt="Submit">
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Under the "head" tag (before the |body background="../images/ingbgrnd.gif"| line) there is a bunch of css code (hundreds of lines, so I am not pasting it here). What it seemed relevant there was the following:

```
.tablebutton
{
BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid;
BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid;
BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid;
BORDER-TOP: 0px solid;
FLOAT: left;
LEFT: 2px;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
PADDING-TOP: 0px;
POSITION: relative
}
.cellbutton
{
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
PADDING-TOP: 0px
}
```

I have figured out how to switch to the frame, input values into Name and Password fields, but whatever method I am trying to click the 'Submit' button, it is not working (error: no such element).

My code:

```
driver.get("http://svr/index.html");
driver.manage().window().maximize();        
driver.findElement(By.linkText("English Sign On")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame("ContentFrame");
driver.findElement(By.name("SOME-USER-ID")).sendKeys("user");
driver.findElement(By.name("SOME-USER-PSWD-TXT")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Submit")).click();
```

This is an application that works only on IE8, so no firebug option (tried Firebug Lite, it did not work either, although it worked with some other external sites). I would greatly appreciate a suggestion regarding what kind of locator do I use for the 'Submit' button (last long line in the code above).

Comment: Please show the `iframe` and the code you are currently executing.

Comment: Done. Added the frame lines and the my code.

Comment: When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Jeff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `By.partialLinkText("Submit")` matches your

```
<input width="143" type="image" border="0" height="38" tabindex="4" src="../english/images/submit.gif" alt="Submit">
```

From [Selenium documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#user-input-filling-in-forms) it seems you could try and select any element on your form and just do submit() on it, and that will trigger the entire form submit.

Ex:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("SOME-USER-PSWD-TXT")).submit();
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to the documentation! That is what I still have to learn to use properly. Your solution worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice. I did not know that. You can also use `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[alt='Submit']")).click();`.

Comment: Ah, cool, so selecting by attribute worked, I'll keep that in mind :D